# Spring Rest API definition using MultiActionController

Tags: java, spring, rest, servlets, web.xml

I'm working on setting up a REST api using Java/Spring/Maven in a JBoss servlet engine and utilising MultiActionController.

What `I want to do is to group requests to a Single controller` for example:
all `/requestA goes to Controller a`, that has several methods for different request, like
-  `/requestA/add.do goes to add-function`

- `/requestA/delete.do goes to delete-function.`

I've been reading the Spring documentation:
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/spring-framework-reference/html/ch18s02.html
and 
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/spring-framework-reference/html/ch16s03.html#mvc-controller-multiaction

But I've got some problems in the dispatcher configuration in the xml.
Does anyone know of a good example how to accomplish this in Spring MVC.

springapp-servlet.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <bean name="/test/*.do" class="org.test.TestControllerA" />
</beans>
```

web.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>springTest</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>springapp</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>springapp</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

and the Java Controller

```
    public class TestControllerA extends MultiActionController {

    @RequestMapping("/TEST")
    public ModelAndView add(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Test42");
    return new ModelAndView();
  }
}
```

Comment: Show us you Spring xml

Comment: how are you doing url mapping?

Comment: Updated with the code

Comment: based on the configuration `/test/add.do` should go to the `add()` is it happening

Comment: I get:

No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/MY-PROJECT-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/test/add.do] in DispatcherServlet with name 'springapp'

in the Jboss log.

Comment: you may have to move the ` @RequestMapping("/TEST")` to class level and change the mapping to ` @RequestMapping("/test")`

Comment: Tried moving the RequestMapping and got it working, when a removed the servlet from the servlet dispacher to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the servlet-mapping

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springapp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Your urls have the extension `*.do` but it is not mapped to `springapp`. So add the above configuration to your `web.xml`

Comment: I get:

No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/MY-PROJECT-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/test/add.do] in DispatcherServlet with name 'springapp'

in the Jboss log.

Comment: Adding the .do and removing the @RequestDefinition helped, had duble mapping in the servlet conf.